# Django serializer returning empty string

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I was hoping somebody could advise my on this: my serializer returns an empty string, despite the data being correct.

```
def foo(self, request, uuid=None):
        data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        logger.error(data)
        serializer = MySerializer(data=data)
        logger.error(serializer.data) #Empty JSON string 
        something.bar(serializer.data, self.request.user)
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

MySerializer:

```
class MySerializer(serializers.Serializer):

    foo1 = serializers.BooleanField()
    foo2 = serializers.CharField(max_length=200, required=True)
    foo3 = serializers.BooleanField()

    class Meta:
        fields = ('foo1',
                  'foo2',
                  'foo3')
```

The data returned by the serializer from serializer.data:
foo1: '', foo2: False, foo3: False

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 3):

I believe your answer comes directly from `rest_framework/serializers.py`:

```
@property
def data(self):
    if hasattr(self, 'initial_data') and not hasattr(self, '_validated_data'):
        msg = (
            'When a serializer is passed a `data` keyword argument you '
            'must call `.is_valid()` before attempting to access the '
            'serialized `.data` representation.\n'
            'You should either call `.is_valid()` first, '
            'or access `.initial_data` instead.'
        )
        raise AssertionError(msg)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to call `.is_valid()` on the serializer first with the data and then access the serialized data(which Joey also pointed out).

```
def foo(self, request, uuid=None):
    data = JSONParser().parse(request)
    logger.error(data)
    serializer = MySerializer(data=data)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True) # explicitly call .is_valid() first 
    logger.error(serializer.data) #Empty JSON string  
    something.bar(serializer.data, self.request.user)
    return Response(status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```